# Python output a string only once with random/choice

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to create a small programm in Python which picks a random string out of a list and prints the string. But often the program picks the same string twice.

Is there a way to make sure that every string gets only outputted once?

My code so far:

```
from random import choice
food = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'orange']
print 'You should eat today :' + choice(food)
print 'You should eat tomorrow :' + choice(food)
```

Comment: try something like - for foodItem in food: print foodItem

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about the ordering of the list afterwards, you can just shuffle the list first, and then iterate over it.

```
import random
food = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'orange']
random.shuffle(food)

for f in food:
    print f
```

If you don't need all of them right away, you should just pop an item when you want it (this will exhaust the list).

```
import random
food = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'orange']
random.shuffle(food)

try:
    print food.pop()
except IndexError:
    print "No more food left!"

# ....
# some more code
# I'm hungry!

try:
    print food.pop()
except IndexError:
    print "No more food left!"

# etc.
```

The try ... except is needed to handle the case that you want to grab some food from an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

```
today = choice(food)
tomorrow = today
while tomorrow == today:
    tomorrow = choice(food)
print 'You should eat today : {}'.format(today)
print 'You should eat tomorrow : {}'.format(tomorrow)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `choice`, use [`sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
today, tomorrow = random.sample(food, 2)
```

From the docs:

> `random.sample(population, k)`
>
> Return a `k` length list of unique elements chosen from the `population` sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> food = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'orange']
>>> sample(food, 2)
['banana', 'blueberry']
>>> sample(food, 2)
['orange', 'apple']
>>> today, tomorrow = sample(food, 2)
>>> today
'banana'
>>> tomorrow
'blueberry'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about destroying your list in the process, you can use this function instead of choice.

```
import random

def del_choice(food):
    if food:
        return food.pop(random.randrange(len(food)))
    return None
```

Comment: ...or shuffle the list once and pop randomized elements from it until the list is empty.

Comment: yep...but only if you are not sorting the list again some way between the pop calls ;] actually, there are probably too many use cases to provide a single, solving-all answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this technique.
In this way, you can print all of the elements inside a list one at a time for only once.
just append the ones you've already printed into a new list, sort both of the lists out and later match the list elements or lengths of the two lists.
Either way, If both of the lists match elementwise or lengthwise, break out of the infinite loop!

```
from random import choice
q = 0
k = []
food = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'orange']
food.sort()
while True:
  i = choice(food)
  if i in k:
    pass
  else:
    print('You should eat today :' + i)
    k.append(i)
    k.sort()
  q += 1
  if k == food:
    break
```